# Unable to specyfing structured datatype in NumPy

Tags: python, numpy

I have to read the following binary file:

```
fname = '3B42RT.2014082603.7.bin'
with open(fname, 'rb') as fi:

  dt = np.dtype([('>b1',2880),('>i2',(480,1440)),('>i2',(480,1440)),('>b1',(480,1440)),('>i2',(480,1440))])

  data = np.fromfile(fi, dtype=dt)
```

But, I obtained the following error message:

```
TypeError: data type not understood
```

I had put the 'dt' based on the the following IDL program which correctly reads the data:

```
file = "3B42RT.2014082603.7.bin"

data = {header: bytarr(2880.0), precip: intarr(1440.0,480.0), precip_error: intarr(1440.0,480.0), $
      source_of_estimate: bytarr(1440.0,480.0), precip_uncal: intarr(1440.0,480.0)}

close, 1
openr, 1, file
readu, 1, data
close, 1

precip = swap_endian(data.precip)

print, precip
```

I want to read the file correctly using Python.
I think the problem in my code is in defining the structured data type in NumPy. Interested to know if someone is familiar with this kind of problem. I went through the following NumPy documentation, but due to my little knowledge of Python, I could not figure out it.
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html#accessing-and-modifying-field-names

Comment: If the data file is required, it is here: ftp://trmmopen.gsfc.nasa.gov/pub/merged/3B42RT/3B42RT.2014082603.7.bin.gz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first element of each tuple in a NumPy dtypes must be the field name.  Try this:

```
np.dtype([
    ('field1', '>b1',2880),
    ('field2', '>i2',(480,1440)),
    ('field3', '>i2',(480,1440)),
    ('field4', '>b1',(480,1440)),
    ('field5', '>i2',(480,1440)),
    ])
```

Comment: Thanks, I will certainly +1 getting 15 points. BTW can I put it in the dictionary form so that fieldname could be accessed easily?

Comment: Once you read using a dtype like that you will get a "structured array" (formerly known as recarray).  This has named fields so you can do `data['field2'][34][100]` etc.

Comment: There are still problem with '>b1','>i2','>i2','>b1',and '>i2' as compared to IDL, right?

Comment: What problem is that?  You may need to post a new question if it's somewhat different from this one.

Comment: Because output of data['field2'] are different than of IDL.

Comment: Sounds like time for a new question.  :)  I suggest looking at the endian swap done in the IDL code, maybe you need to use an `<i` instead of `>i` or so.  I upvoted you so you'll hopefully be able to post questions more quickly someday soon!

Comment: Thanks, hope to meet with you new question soon.

Comment: Here is a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25539459/unable-to-define-datatype-in-numpy